# "Unfortunately app has stopped" error?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I'm trying to write a basic drawing Android app for android and test it on Genymotion, but I can't click on the app icon (it says "Unfortunately [app] has stopped.")

I'm not sure if the three private variables should be under the MainActivity class? Or that it has to do with my AndroidManifest.xml file. Can someone look over my code?

My MainActivity.java file:

```
package edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Paint myPaint;
private ImageButton currPaint;
private myView drawView;

public void paintClicked(View view) {
    if (view != currPaint) {
        // update color
        ImageButton imgView = (ImageButton) view;
        String color = view.getTag().toString();

        drawView.setColor(color);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint_pressed));
        currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paint));
        currPaint = (ImageButton)view;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myView mV = new myView(this, null);
    setContentView(mV);

    drawView = (myView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);

    LinearLayout paintLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_colors);
    currPaint = (ImageButton) paintLayout.getChildAt(0);
    currPaint.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.paint_pressed));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

---

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Logcat:

```
[2014-02-11 23:04:43 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:EOF
[2014-02-11 23:04:43 - DeviceMonitor] Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
[2014-02-11 23:04:43 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2014-02-11 23:04:44 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2014-02-11 23:04:45 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
[2014-02-11 23:04:46 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 4
[2014-02-11 23:04:47 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 5
[2014-02-11 23:04:48 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 6
[2014-02-11 23:04:49 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 7
[2014-02-11 23:04:50 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 8
[2014-02-11 23:04:51 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 9
[2014-02-11 23:04:52 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 10
[2014-02-11 23:04:53 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 11
[2014-02-11 23:07:14 - Logcat] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:774)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:396)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:347)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:444)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:531)
```

---

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/brush"
            android:src="@drawable/brush" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2.myView
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/paint_colors"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/large_brush"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/large_brush"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#FF787878"
                android:contentDescription="@string/paint"
                android:onClick="paintClicked"
                android:src="@drawable/paint"
                android:tag="#FF787878" />
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

myView class:

```
package edu.berkeley.cs160.opalkale.prog2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class myView extends View {
private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
private int paintColor = 0xFF787878;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

public void setColor(String newColor){
    //set color     
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor); 
    }

public myView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    // view given size
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw view
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // detect user touch
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: setContentView(mV); is missing in your code..

Comment: @kalyanpvs even with it not commented out, I still have the same problem

Comment: @Opal You are using LinearLayout and imageButtons in your layout so create a layout in the res/layout folder with your desired views and assign them same ids.

Comment: @kalyanpvs I created a layout. I'll post the code to that as well

Comment: @Opal replace this line like this..setContentView(mV); into setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a common problem with manifest your program "Unfortunately app has stopped" may be caused due to `Manifest file`, Because you have two classes:

So use this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:name=".myView"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: @HasAlTaiar Instead I just uncommented myView mV = new myView(this, null); and setContentView(mV);, where myView is a class that extends View. I still am not able to click on my app. Any pointers?

Comment: no, use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_name);` otherwise you'll get an error..:)

Comment: so should I change it to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and then comment out `myView mV = new myView(this, null);` and `drawView = (myView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);` ?

Comment: yes, use `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name.xml);` in your program :)

Comment: I'm still not able to open the app and getting the same error :(

Comment: Don't use `myView mV = new myView(this, null);` in your code, use only `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name.xml);` delete your object for `myView`..:)

Comment: By the way tell me, do you have your `myView` class??

Comment: so Undo all those things, it's just a common `manifest file problem`, UNDO THOSE things, don't use `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name.xml);`..firstly undo and i'll tell something to change your manifest first do undo..

Comment: I replaced the section of code you wrote in the given section in my `androidmanifest.xml` file and it has not resolved the problem yet unfortunately

Comment: check your layout file and ensure that it does not have any bad xml (misspelling, etc). If that happens, sometimes it blows up when you try to load it. The validation in the editor is not that great

Answer (score 2):

`setContentView(Id);` is missing in your code.So it is giving you `NullPointerException`

Set some of the view to your Activity like

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

NPE- Null Pointer Exception. No call to setContentView.

Also,

```
drawView = (myView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);
```

what is your myView ?

Please set myView as the view for your activity or call setContentView with the layout where R.id.drawing is.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `layout`.Your `layout` is missing.   Use  `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove comments from this line ,

```
// setContentView(mV);
```